# Problem with line.new that extends indefinitely until the first update occurs

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm coding a script that draws some lines on the graph using a code like this:

```
//@version=5
indicator('Lines', '', true)

//Menu
left = input.int(0, 'Left Extension', 0, step=1)
right = input.int(9, 'Right Extension', 0, step=1)

//Variables
ATR = ta.atr(14)
in_0 = ta.vwap(hlc3)
ln = in_0-ATR

_draw(lvl) =>
    var id_1 = line.new(na, na, na, na)
    line.set_xy1(id_1, bar_index-left, lvl)
    line.set_xy2(id_1, bar_index+right, lvl)

//Plot
_draw(ln)
```

When I open the layout that contains the indicator, the drawn lines extend indefinitely to the right until the first price update occurs, as shown in this image:
[image]

By removing the two extension options from "line.set", the problem disappears. For example, like this:

```
line.set_xy1(id_1, bar_index[1], lvl)
line.set_xy2(id_1, bar_index, lvl)
```

Is there another way to control the extension of a line in both directions and avoid this issue?

Comment: I am unable to duplicate your error with your code. The line plots as expected for me when I first add it to my chart

Comment: The issue doesn't occur when the indicator is added to the layout. When the indicator is added and the layout is then saved and closed, if I re-open the layout while the stock has no trades at that moment, then the indefinitely extended line appears.

Comment: Sounds like a bug with TradingView to me- if it is, you probably cant do much besides put in a bug ticket